# std::promise/std::future vs std::condition_variable in C++

Tags: c++11, concurrency, promise, future, condition-variable

Signaling between threads can be achieved with `std::promise`/`std::future` or with good old condition variables. Can someone provide examples/use case where one would be a better choice over the other ?

I know that CVs could be used to signal multiple times between threads. Can you give example with `std::future`/`promise` to signal multiple times?

Also, is `std::future::wait_for` equivalent in performance with `std::condition_variable::wait`?
Let's say I need to wait on multiple futures in a queue as a consumer; does it make sense to go through each of them and check if they are ready like below ?

```
for(auto it = activeFutures.begin(); it!= activeFutures.end();) {
            if(it->valid() && it->wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::ready) {
                Printer::print(std::string("+++ Value " + std::to_string(it->get()->getBalance())));
                activeFutures.erase(it);
                
            } else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this CppCon talk w.r.t to condition variables which starts at time 25:00,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paK38WAq8WY

Answer (score 1):

> can some one provide examples/use case where 1 would be a better
> choice over other ?

These are 2 different tools of the standard library.
In order to give an example where 1 would be better over the other you'd have to come up with a scenario where both tools are a good fit.
However, these are different levels of abstractions to what they do and what they are good for.

from cppreference (emphasis mine):

**Condition variables**

> A condition variable is a ***synchronization primitive*** that allows
> multiple threads to communicate with each other. It allows some number
> of threads to wait (possibly with a timeout) for notification from
> another thread that they may proceed. A condition variable is always
> associated with a mutex.

**Futures**

> The standard library provides **facilities to obtain values** that are
> returned and to catch exceptions that are thrown **by asynchronous tasks**
> (i.e. functions launched in separate threads). These values are
> communicated in a shared state, in which the asynchronous task may
> write its return value or store an exception, and which may be
> examined, waited for, and otherwise manipulated by other threads that
> hold instances of **std::future or std::shared_future** that reference

As you can see, a condition variable is a synchronization primitive whereas a future is a facility used to communicate results of asynchronous tasks.

The condition variable can be used in a variety of scenarios where you need to synchronizes multiple threads, however you would typically use a `std::future` when you have tasks/jobs/work to do and you need it done without interrupting your main flow, aka asynchronously.

so in my opinion a good example where you would use a future + promise is when you need to run a long running calculation and get/wait_for the result at a later point of time. In comparison to a condition variable, where you would have had to basically implement `std::future` + `std::promise` on your own, possibly using `std::condition_variable` somewhere internally.

> can you give example with std::future/promise to signal multiple times?

have a look at the toy example from [shared_future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future)

> Also is std::future::wait_for equivalent in performance with std::condition_variable::wait?

well, GCC's implementation of `std::future::wait_for` uses `std::condition_variable::wait_for` which correlates with my explanation of the difference between the two. So as you can understand `std::future::wait_for` adds a very small performance overhead to `std::condition_variable::wait_for`